# How to upload .pptx to my skydrive account in java code

Tags: java, upload, onedrive

I want to make a program which upload presentation to my skydrive account and return me link by which everybody could see this presentation. Does anybody have some sample codes, advices?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a concrete answer but maybe you find useful info here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-134C

Comment: well, i dont know exactly about skydrive, but as always with Things like this you should do some research on the API provided, and your question somehow suggests you didnt do any research... have a look here: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/12/07/skydrive-apis-for-docs-and-photos-now-ready-to-cloud-enable-apps-on-windows-8-windows-phone-and-more.aspx or just google it yourself...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I already red these articles, but I dont know how can i get the constans **ACCESS_TOKEN** which is used in examples´ requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn about OAuth and Skydrive API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx

and about LiveConnect's RESTful services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx